# MS Excel: custom money format

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, cells

Need to represent decimal number as "## hrn. ## kop.".
Example:

```
1.2 => 1 hrn. 20 kop.
3 => 3 hrn. 00 kop.
```

I've created custom cell format:

```
0," hrn. "#0" kop."
```

Result is:

```
1.2 => 1, hrn. 20 kop.
```

How to remove this comma after 1? Is there another way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format:

```
# " hrn". #0" kop."
```

Or modify yours to:

```
0, " hrn". #0" kop."
```

It's working for me.